# Unable to print array in alphabatic order list

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, arraylist

I want to show some tags on my page, These are prefixed with authors-, publisher-
foreg : author-authorname, publisher-publishername etc.

Also, show those tags in alphabetic order list like

```
A:
Amiley
Amina
B:
Bruno
Browni
```

I write a code but the main issues is:
 - My last element repeated again and again , i don't know why.. Here is my code that i write in file

```
    public static function author_tags(){
     $product_tags = get_terms( 'product_tag');
     array_splice($product_tags, 0, 1);
     $author_tag = array();
     $output = "";
     $previous = null;
     foreach($product_tags as $list){
     $chk = substr($list->slug, 0, 6);
      if($chk == 'author'){
       $first_letter = ucfirst(substr($list->name,7,1));
       $tag_url = "http://example.com/product-tag/".$list->slug;
       $output = "<li class='list-tags'><a href='".$tag_url."'>".substr($list->name,7)."</a></li>";
      }
     if($previous != $first_letter){
      echo "<h1><a href=''>".$first_letter."</a></h1>";
      }
     $previous = $first_letter;
     echo $output;
     } 
    }
```

Output:

```
A:
Amiley
Amina
B:
Bruno
Browni
-----------
----------
Y:
Yaomi
Yaomi
Yaomi
Yaomi
Yaomi
```

Comment: If you leave some example output for `get_terms( 'product_tag')` it will make it easier for other user to investigate the case :) e.g. `$product_tags = [....]`

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 848
            [name] => author-A J J Ratcliff
            [slug] => author-a-j-j-ratcliff
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 848
            [taxonomy] => product_tag
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
        ))

Comment: if you check the full array, it prob has the same data repeated, a foreach loop is predictable, when it reaches the end of the array it will stop. Is that how the function ends? you are missing the closing bracket so unless you have something after your foreach, its more than likely that

Comment: Why are you using `array_splice`?